# How do I program a resize handle on a delphi TFrame?

Tags: delphi, windows-messages

I have a TFrame that I want to be able to resize by clicking and dragging the bottom-right corner. The functionality should be;

When the mouse moves over the bottom-right corner the cursor should change to reflect that the frame can be resized. If not over the bottom corner the cursor should be the standard arrow.

There will be controls on top of the frame at runtime so I can't use the OnMouseMove event. So I use this;

```
private
  procedure WMSetCursor(var Msg: TWMSetCursor); message WM_SETCURSOR;

procedure TfraApplet.WMSetCursor(var Msg: TWMSetCursor);
var
  Point: TPoint;
begin

  Point := ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos);
  Label1.Caption := 'X:' + IntToStr(Point.X) + ' Y:' + IntToStr(Point.Y);

  // Resize area (bottom right)
  if (Point.X >= (Width - 10)) and (Point.Y >= (Height - 10)) then
    Screen.Cursor := crSizeNWSE
  else
    Screen.Cursor := crDefault;

end;
```

However as soon as the cursor gets set to crSizeNWSE my programs stops receiving the WM_SETCURSOR windows message.

Is there a different windows message I can receive when the cursor is not set as the default arrow?

Comment: You aren't setting the result of the message

Comment: What made you decide that you stop receiving the message?

Comment: David, thanks for the pointer. How to I return a value? If I use a function returning a boolean I get an error when compiling.

Comment: Sertac, I could be wrong, but the cursor does not revert to default when you move away from the bottom-right corner. Maybe I should have stated that fact.

Comment: @srayner: Set `Msg.Result := LongInt(True)`.

Comment: @Ken Technically you should cast to `LRESULT` since that is the type of a message result. Using that type will avoid surprises when moving to 64 bit. Personally I'd just set it to 1!

Comment: @David: D2007 defines the TWMSetCursor.Result as `LongInt` in Messages.pas, so technically it should probably be `LongInt(LongBool(True))` in my example. I see that XE7 does define it as `LRESULT`, though, so you're correct. It should *properly* be `LRESULT(LongBool(True))`, I think.

Comment: @KenWhite OK. I guess then D2007 is deficient. I do recall that Emba made a real hash of Windows types back in those days. They had to get it together for 64 bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that the frame stops receiving `WM_SETCURSOR` messages, it's that he cursor gets stuck set at crSizeNWSE. When you switch back to setting `crDefault` to `Screen.Cursor`, what happens is that the VCL sends a `WM_SETCURSOR` to the frame to have it set the default cursor. In effect no cursor ever becomes set. A cursor have to be set if you want it to be changed from the previous one, replace the last part with:

```
  // Resize area (bottom right)
  if (Point.X >= (Width - 10)) and (Point.Y >= (Height - 10)) then begin
    winapi.Windows.SetCursor(Screen.Cursors[crSizeNWSE]);
    Message.Result := 1;
  end else
    inherited;
```

As an alternative, you can handle `WM_NCHITTEST` to define the area as a sizing area, and then the default window procedure of the frame will set the appropriate cursor when it's handling `WM_SETCURSOR`:

```
procedure TfraApplet.WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest);
var
  Point: TPoint;
begin

  Point := ScreenToClient(SmallPointToPoint(Message.Pos));
  Label1.Caption := 'X:' + IntToStr(Point.X) + ' Y:' + IntToStr(Point.Y);

  // Resize area (bottom right)
  if (Point.X >= (Width - 10)) and (Point.Y >= (Height - 10)) then
    Message.Result := HTBOTTOMRIGHT
  else
    inherited;

end;
```

As an added benefit you won't have to write additional code for resizing the frame.

Comment: I went with your first solution of calling inherited instead of setting Screen.Cursor to crDefault. It works perfectly.